# How do I fix Minecraft 1.17.1 Zoomed in display Problem?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, pc, windows-7

So recently, I have been starting to play 1.17, however each time I open it, It comes up with this kind of zoomed in partly rendering in display.I understand when you see this picture me desktop is Windows 7 and I know Windows 10 is free however, it just does not work on my computer. I have went into setting and video setting and tried to change anything that can possible relate to the problem but nothing is working. Does anyone have any suggestions on how i fix this? My friends and I are doing a survival server and i really want to join!
[image: Menu screen]. [image: Options display].

Comment: Welcome to arqade.se ^^ Please take the [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour), and read the [help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) if in need of guidance.

Comment: I shared that first image in a group chat (because it looks hilarious) and someone said "That issue is usually caused by outdated graphics drivers". So check that, I guess.

Comment: How do i do that @FabianRöling

Comment: Or even if you know how to fix it would be amazing @FabianRöling

Answer (score 1):

A [Minecraft bug tracker expert](https://bugs.mojang.com/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=violine1101) told me that this issue is [MC-218803](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-218803) (which also has some other hilarious screenshots). This issue is caused by using either very old hardware or a very old graphics driver. These were technically unsupported for a long time already, but now that 1.17 requires OpenGL 3.2 or above, you really start getting extreme issues with it.

You can try updating your graphics driver. Problematically, how you do that depends very much on which graphics card you have. So first, you need to figure that out. I don't use Windows myself, but Google is always helpful:

> Right click on "This PC" or "My computer".
> Choose "Properties".
> Now a new window will open, showing all the main specifications like RAM, CPU, Windows version, etc. Here, go to the left pane & choose "Device manager".
> Now select "Display Adapter".
> Here you'll get all the information regarding your graphics card.
> <sub>(minimally changed from [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-check-what-graphics-card-you-have-on-Windows-7))</sub>

Once you know the name of your graphics card, google something like "how to update *[name of graphics card]* drivers" and you should get instructions. If it then turns out that your graphics drivers are already up to date, you will likely not be able to play Minecraft 1.17+ on that computer.